# Is it possible to implement analytics on OS permissions prompts in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, analytics

I want to measure the push notifications opt-in rates for my app. I am curious if it is possible to track whether the user chooses to enable or disable push notifications when the OS prompt appears and users taps on either enable or disable.

Note: This is not a question asking to check if there is a way to check if the notifications are enabled are not. I know this is possible.

This question is asking if it is possible to track what the user has tapped on when the native OS permissions prompt (not a custom one) is displayed to them. E.g. 1. The app request the OS to prompt OS notification permissions prompt to appear. 2. The user taps on enable 3. App logs an analytics event that the user has tapped on enable.

Comment: What became of this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you can give it a whirl and let me know how it works. Basically you'd make the request to register for remote notifications and then implement the `UIApplicationDelegate` method for handling success and failure.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let application = UIApplication.shared

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        application.delegate = self
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // code to handle log success
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        // code to log failure
    }
}
```